# how do i use notepad++ search in files to show specific rows

Tags: notepad++

im trying to find specific rows in multiple files i have.all files have the same start/end strings to find the rows between them.
im trying to show all rows between 1st search string "items:" and ends in 2nd search string "done items"
i dont know how to use regex.

if you can provide me the specific search i need to input i would really really thank you

example:

```
items:
box
bottle
briefcase
items done

items:
car
cradle
candle
done items

items:
door
desk
done items
```

Comment: Your first block ends with `items done` instead of `done items`, is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming the first block ends with `done items` and not `items done`**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^items:\s+\K[\s\S]+?(?=^done items)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  items:            # literally
  \s+               # 1 or more spaces (including linebreaks
  \K                # forget all we have seen until this position
  [\s\S]+?          # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  (?=^done items)   # positive lookahead, make sure we have "done items" at the beginning of line
```

**Screenshot (1rst match):**

[image]

**Screenshot (2nd match):**

[image]

...and so on when you click on <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your help
im trying to do this in search in files. to scan many txt files. and this feature dosnt have wrap around. what should i do?

Comment: when using this command in search files it shows me only 1 row for each file. it should have shown me more than that

Comment: @EladNa: That's the way Npp works, it shows only the first line of the matched block. May be you should write a script.  What are you trying to do **exactly**? Edit your question and add some example files, actuallly, you show only one file.

Comment: i have more than 10000 txt files that contains irrelevant text. but in around 30% of them i have info i need to extract to one big txt file. i need to search all of those file to who have the info i need and to show them in search results so i can copy them.
all those files who HAVE the data has the same line that starts and same line that ends
lets take this example:
file 1:
names
alvin
james 
owen
end

Comment: file 2:
chris
nathan
end

file 3
moses
steve
jose
jim
brad
harrison
end

i need all the info between "names" and "end" will show up in the search results no matter how many lines they are. sometime it will be 1 line some time will be 8. 
thanks for your help

Comment: @EladNa: As I said above, Npp can't do such job. You have to write a script.

Comment: i dont know to do that.:(
is there a way you can help me with that?